# ten times {as / more} intelligent

Tags: comparative-constructions

Would you show me if these mean the same thing?

Other than that, would you show me other(s) way to express following?

> 1.John is ten times **as** intelligent **as** David.
>
> 2.John is ten times **more** intelligent **than** David.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your specific examples are equivalent. But note that many adjectives don't work well (or at all) with the ***more** [adj] **than*** form, because we don't normally use forms like ***more big, tall, old*** etc. (they'd be ***bigger, taller, older***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers They aren't equivalent. If you're 1m and I'm twice as tall as you, I'm 2m. If I'm 50% taller than you I'm 1.5m. That means I'm .5m taller than you. If I'm two times taller, I'm 200% taller, so I'm 2m taller than you. So I'm 3m. Right? ( - or not?)

Comment: @Araucaria: Nice try, but I think that's been done to death under Faisal's answer! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got "He's two times smaller then me" today in class. Erm, stumped me ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria: Apparently there's a [recognised problem in this area](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22expressions+used+to+compare+parts+of+objects+or+amounts+%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) when it comes to teaching/talking about basic arithmetic comparisons (what the linguists call *partitive comparative expressions*) with "nonstandard black dialect speakers". I didn't read that link in detail, but it looks like this is because they actually *conceptualise* such things differently, as well as using different words to describe such relationships.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following explanation might not make sense at first, and the reason for that is that human intelligence is, as yet, *unquantifiable*:

Assume that David's intelligence = X

1. "John is ten times as intelligent as David", means that John's intelligence = 10 * X
2. "John is ten times more intelligent than David", means that John's intelligence = X + (10 * X) = 11 * X

So basically they convey the same meaning: John is considerably more intelligent than David.

Now when comparing two *quantifiable* amounts:

Assume that David is 5 years old

1. "John is ten times as old as David", means that John is 10 * 5 = 50 years old.
2. "John is ten times older than David", means that John is 5 + (10 * 5) = 55 years old.

Comment: I think almost no native speakers would assume John is 55 (as opposed to 50-ish) in your final example. Your *quantifiable/unquantifiable* distinction reflects a mathematical mindset that isn't manifest in ordinary *English* usage.

Comment: I agree. I have an engineering/mathematics background, hence the misplaced formulas. I suppose people will just assign the same significance to John's intelligence or age regardless of the wording.

Comment: Say John has £4 and David has £1. I really don't believe *anyone* would say *"John is **three** times richer than/as rich as David"* unless they were specifically intending to follow that "unacceptable" statement with exactly your distinction. Which would convince no-one, I feel, but it might pass a few minutes down the pub debating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing. Like another person said, using "as" is more versatile because you can put any adjective in there without changing it ("ten times as dedicated," "ten times as strong," "ten times as fast," etc.). But using "more" is perfectly understandable as well, but you would have to modify the adjectives.

1. "Ten times more intelligent" = okay
2. "Ten times more strong" = not okay
3. "Ten times stronger" = okay
4. "Ten times smarter" = okay